# How to add an SD card to genymotion?

Tags: genymotion

In genymotion settings->storage there is only the internal storage, no SD card.

Is there a way to have a SD card also?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's already some emulation of SD card (external) storage in Genymotion that might work for you, depending on what you're trying to do. Although Settings->Storage doesn't show it separately as External Storage like you might expect, Genymotion does emulate external storage. The size of files stored there will be reflected in the totals shown under Internal Storage by Settings-Storage.

Running in Genymotion, an app using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` or `.getAbsolutePath()` will get back `/storage/emulated/<userId>`, where `userId`=0 if the app is running as Owner, and 10, 11, 12, etc. if the app is running as another user or restricted/managed profile.  The Android framework actually maps this for you to `/mnt/shell/emulated/<userId>`, which is why you won't find `/storage/emulated/<userId>` if you use a shell to poke around.

The paths `/sdcard` and `/mnt/sdcard` are symlinks to `/storage/emulated/legacy`, which is basically the Owner's storage.  Don't use these in your apps, since they might not exist everywhere and/or your app might not have access to them if not running as Owner.  They are just there to support legacy hardcoded apps.

Not being sure what you're trying to do, it's probably also worth mentioning that Genymotion now supports VirtualBox shared folders which will appear under `/mnt/shared` inside your VM. Check their [Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+GenymotionEmulator/posts/d2ogLdU1rZw) for instructions.