# How do I access the genymotion virtual devices' sd card?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-machine, android-sdcard, genymotion

I'm new to android development, I'm trying to access the photos that I've taken from the genymotion virtual device, in the code there's the following line:

```
  final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM", "pic.jpg");
```

According to the android Studio website, `getExternalStorageDirectory()` Returns the primary shared/external storage directory. After looking at the virtual machine's configuration, I've found the path `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Custom Phone - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 768x1280\sdcard.vdi` and I can't open the file since its extension is `.vdi`. 
Is there another way for me to access my sdcard in a way that all the saved data is clearly displayed ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25122574/6950238) answer and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18530114/6950238) question.